# Append contents of multiple fields into one field based on the condition of their contents

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I am designing an Access 2013 database to record various attributes of truck chassis we receive to put bodies on for our clients.  There are several fields that record conditions of certain parts of the chassis (BUMPER, LEFT_ FENDER, TIRES, WINDSHIELD, etc.).  The default value of these fields is “GOOD”, i.e. no problems found.   However, if the value of one or more of these fields is something different (DENTED, CHIPPED, CRACKED, etc.), I would like to combine the sum of all these “non-good” fields into a single field called “COMMENTS” for each record.  I’ve tried using an append query, but to check for multiple conditions on multiple fields with an immediate action after each condition is met (add field content to CONTENTS field) is beyond the scope of my coding ability.  I need to perform several “If [FIELDX]<>”GOOD” then [COMMENTS]=[COMMENTS] & [FIELDX]” calculations.  Any ideas how to do this in SQL view, VBA, Macros, or Expression Builder?

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are entering the values in a form. There will be several Text-boxes linked to individual chassis parts and one to comment (Say Text123). For each of the chassis-parts Text-boxes , write code for the "On Exit" event that concatenates Text123 with the field-name associated with the given Text-box, after performing the `<> "Good"` check. Then when you save the record, the Comment field will have the concatenated value.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do this in VBA and Allen Browne's site is a good place to start http://allenbrowne.com/tips.html. It hasn't been updated for a while 2010 but a lot of the basic concepts remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks.  I decided to put the code in the BeforeUpdate event of the form.  That way it compiles all "non-GOOD" entries into a field called COMPILED_COMMENTS on each CREATE or UPDATE action and then merges it with the COMMENTS field into a final field called TOTAL_COMMENTS.    One final question...  This info will be exported via a CSV file and imported into an AS400 system.  It would be nice to have a line feed between each comment, but due to the nature of CSV files, I don't see how it can be accomplished (thus the "|" character between each comment).  I guess doing a find / replace after it is in the AS400 system is my only solution, true? My code is below...

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS = ""
If Me.UPHOLSTERY <> "GOOD" Then
        Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS = "[UPHOLSTERY CONDITION] - " & Me.UPHOLSTERY
    End If
If Me.REAR_GLASS <> "GOOD" Then
        Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS = Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS & " | [REAR GLASS CONDITION] - " &     Me.REAR_GLASS
    End If
If Me.WINDSHIELD <> "GOOD" Then
        Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS = Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS & " | [WINDSHIELD CONDITION] - " & Me.WINDSHIELD
    End If
If Me.FENDERS <> "GOOD" Then
        Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS = Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS & " | [FENDER CONDITION] - " & Me.FENDERS
    End If
If Me.HOOD <> "GOOD" Then
        Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS = Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS & " | [HOOD CONDITION] - " & Me.HOOD
    End If
If Me.REAR_OF_CAB <> "GOOD" Then
        Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS = Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS & " | [REAR OF CAB CONDITION] - " & Me.REAR_OF_CAB
    End If
If Me.DRIVER_DOOR <> "GOOD" Then
        Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS = Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS & " | [DRIVER DOOR CONDITION] - " & Me.DRIVER_DOOR
    End If
 If Me.PASSENGER_DOOR <> "GOOD" Then
        Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS = Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS & " | [PASSENGER DOOR CONDITION] - " & Me.PASSENGER_DOOR
    End If
    If Me.FRONT_BUMPER <> "GOOD" Then
        Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS = Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS & " | [FRONT BUMPER CONDITION] - " & Me.FRONT_BUMPER
    End If
If Me.TIRES <> "GOOD" Then
        Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS = Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS & " | [TIRES CONDITION] - " & Me.TIRES
    End If
If Me.CAB_INTERIOR <> "GOOD" Then
        Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS = Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS & " | [CAB INTERIOR CONDITION] - " & Me.CAB_INTERIOR
    End If
Me.TOTAL_COMMENTS = ">>COMMENTS<< -  " & Me.COMMENTS & "   |   >>COMPILED COMMENTS<< -  " & Me.COMPILED_COMMENTS
        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be inclined to use an object orientated method, where you access each control in turn, gathering the relevant information as you go.

To test the following code add a button to your form call btnRun.

You don't need to know the textbox names, all you do is add an "X" in the text-box(s) tag property.

This code will inspect each of the text-boxes Tag property, and if the Tag property contains an "X" the code will extract the Textbox content (as long as it does not contain "Good"). The extracted text is added to the string variable strComment and then it is passed back to the function "fMakeCommentFld".

**Update:-**
I have updated the code so that it extracts the name of the text box from the associated label and then adds it to the comment text generated by the routine.

```
Private Sub btnRun_Click()
'Add a button to your form called btnRun to test this code

        MsgBox " >>> " & fMakeCommentFld
        'Me.txtCOMMENTS = fMakeCommentFld
End Sub


Private Function fMakeCommentFld() As String
Dim Ctrl As Control
Dim strComment As String
Dim strCaption As String

      For Each Ctrl In Me.Controls
        If Ctrl.ControlType = acTextBox Then    'Only Check the TextBox's
            If Mid(Ctrl.Tag, 1, 1) = "X" Then   'And then only if there is an X in the Tag property

                If Ctrl.Value <> "Good" Then    'If NOT GOOD then append to the strComment Variable

                    'The following line takes the Caption from the TextBox Label
                    strCaption = "[" & Ctrl.Controls(0).Caption & " CONDITION] - "
                    strComment = strComment & ", " & strCaption & Ctrl.Value & vbLf
                End If

            End If
         End If
      Next

      strComment = Mid(strComment, 2)           'Strip off the leading comma ","

      fMakeCommentFld = strComment              'Pass the result back to the function

End Function      'fMakeCommentFld
```